# Can't seem to get jQuery .on to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to set up client side validations in a specific way.  I have some forms that are dynamic and won't be shown until a button is clicked or some action is performed.  So, here is what I'm doing:

```
$(function() {
    $('#content').on('load', 'form', function(e) {
        /* every form will be inside of div#content */
        setUpStuff();
    });
});
```

Then if a button is pressed:

```
$('#my-button').click(function() {
    displayForm();
    $('form').trigger('load');
});
```

The problem is that this function bound to fire when that event is triggered never fires. I know div#content exists once the page loads, since it is static.  The form is what is dynamic.  However, even if throw the form in the page as static markup and it is available upon page load, `$('form').trigger('load');` still does not work.

Where am I going wrong with this code?

Comment: There's only one `#content` button yeah?

Comment: Try using a custom event name, the load event is known to not bubble properly, though i'm not sure why it isn't bubbling when you manually trigger it.

Comment: @KevinB can you put this as an answer so I can accept it?  This is exactly the problem. I've been up too long!  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a custom event name, the `load` event is known to not bubble properly, and in this case doesn't really describe what is happening anyway.

```
$(function() {
    $('#content').on('create', 'form', function(e) {
        /* every form will be inside of div#content */
        setUpStuff();
    });
    $('#my-button').click(function() {
        displayForm();
       $('form').trigger('create');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

nvm, looks like you got it :)

I think i know what you are getting at, have you tried using the .load() method?

```
$('#my-button').click(function() {
    displayForm();
    $('form').load(function(){
     setUpStuff();
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/